# How do I disable CVS Sticky Option -kk for keyword substitution?

Tags: version-control, cvs, keyword-substitution

I have a file in cvs that has Sticky Options set to `-kk`.  This replaces all cvs keywords with just the keyword name to facilitate diffs.   For example, `$Author: Alex B$` becomes `$Author$`.

How do I disable the `-kk` behavior and get back to "normal" cvs where keywords are substituted in?   I've tried `rm`'ing the file and updating, I've tried `cvs update -A` and neither changes the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cvs update -kkv <filename>
```

will reset the sticky options to `keyword` and `value`

**Edit:**  Corrected `checkout` to `update`, thanks to [Alex B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6180/alex-b) for the correction.

Comment: Hi Ken,   checkout works on modules, not files - but your answer helped me solve my problem.   If you edit your answer (checkout -> update), I'll accept it and delete my answer.

Comment: Also you need to do a `cvs commit -f -m <message> <filename>`

Answer (score 2):

Running a cvs status on the file still results in "sticky options" being set, for example:

`Sticky options: -kk`

To remove these completely, edit the CVS/Entries file and remove the '-kk' from the relevent entry.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
cvs admin -kkv <filename>
```

to change the mode permanently. Using

```
cvs update -kkv <filename>
```

will only change it on your local machine